# Sqlsrv on mac os xampp

Tags: macos, xampp, localhost, sqlsrv

I need to start the server, but i have an error: 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() 
Please tell me is there any way to add extension sqlsrv for xampp server on mac os
Please save my day